# Hiding/Removing an ImageView from RecyclerView

Tags: android, json, listview, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView which loads the following from a ViewHolder.

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public ImageView imagePreviewOfEvent; 
    ...(other views)

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        imagePreviewOfEvent = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.listOfTimelinePostsPhotoContainer);
        ...(other views)
    }
}
```

I am populating this RecyclerView using data from a JSON request. The data is full of a list of posts. Some posts will have an image but some will not (almost like a Twitter/Facebook Timeline with posts that may/may not have photos).

If there isn't an image then the JSON returns "null". On my RecyclerView, I want to remove an ImageView from each row in the list based on this. I've tried simply to remove the view by checking a boolean state I store:

```
if (timelineListInformation.getNeedsToRemoveImageView() == true) {
        holder.imagePreviewOfEvent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

When I scroll down the list and scroll back up, posts which had an image associated with it are removed. I've been trying to look at all sorts of answers but haven't found anything. Any thoughts?

Comment: did you use timelineListInformation.get(position).getNeedsToRemoveImageView()
as there should be something like this

Comment: Put an else block and set visibility to VISIBLE there. Since your views get recycled, once you hide imageview in that instance of view, it remains hidden until you make it visible again.

Comment: Thanks for the response guys. The answer from JudgedPluto worked perfectly! But...is this the most efficient way of doing it? Rather than just getting the job done, I'm trying to understand the best method. If it is, great if not then what else could I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try instead this one.

```
holder.imagePreviewOfEvent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
if (timelineListInformation.getNeedsToRemoveImageView() == false) {
    holder.imagePreviewOfEvent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! So simple. Thank you. Just out of interest...is this the most efficient way of doing it? Rather than just getting the job done, I'm trying to understand the best method. If it is, great if not then what else could I do?

Comment: Actually, this is the most efficient way. Because how the `RecyclerView` recycles views, there will be some views that use the data from some other items that are shown in `RecyclerView` (i.e. Setting Visibility to GONE). So when you binding the items to the view every time, you should reset the data used in the view. `holder.imagePreviewOfEvent.setVisibility(View.GONE);` does the trick and if you want to show the `ImageView`, you can check the condition and then set the visibility.

Comment: Right understood. Thank you very much for this. Something so simple which I missed. I was so worried this wasn't the best method of doing it but seems that it is :). Thanks for clearing that up! Btw I have this in the  onBindViewHolder method which is where it should be placed right?

Comment: you can place this in `onBindViewHolder()`. just replace it to the code that you used to check the condition.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
if (timelineListInformation.getNeedsToRemoveImageView() == true) {
    holder.imagePreviewOfEvent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}else{
holder.imagePreviewOfEvent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```